# Serializing optionally nested structures: Difference between QueryDict and normal dict?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm running into weird behavior when writing nested structures with django-rest and then trying to test them using django-rest's test client. The nested child object should be optional.

Here's a sample serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class OptionalChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_b = serializers.IntegerField()
    field_c = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('field_b', 'field_c', )

class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_a = serializers.IntegerField()
    child = OptionalChildSerializer(required=False, many=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('a', 'child',)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # TODO: create nested object.
        pass
```

(I've omitted the code in perform_create, as it's not relevant to the question).

Now, passing a normal dict as data argument works just fine:

```
ser = ParentSerializer(data=dict(field_a=3))
ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

But passing a QueryDict instead will fail:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
ser = ParentSerializer(data=QueryDict("field_a=3"))
ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

ValidationError: {'child': {'field_b': [u'This field is required.'], 'field_c': [u'This field is required.']}}
```

On the actual web site, the API gets a normal dict and thus works fine. During testing however, using something like `client.post('url', data=dict(field_a=3))` will result in a QueryDict being passed to the view, and hence not work.

So my question is: what's the difference between the QueryDict and normal dict? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: In data=QueryDict("field_a=3") should "field_a=3" be quoted? Its not quoted in data=dict(field_a=3)

Comment: Paste you test case code. What is your 'content_type' in request ?

Comment: Ah, I haven't set it, but I guess that makes it multipart/form. I was expecting for django-rest to provide application/json automatically. That's certainly where my QueryDict is coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DRF defines multiple parser classes for parsing the request content having different media types.**

`request.data` will normally be a `QueryDict` or a normal dictionary depending on the parser used to parse the request content.

- **JSONParser:**

It parses the JSON request content i.e. content with `.media_type` as `application/json`.

- **FormParser**

It parses the  HTML form content. Here, **`request.data` is populated with a `QueryDict` of data.** These have `.media_type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

- **MultiPartParser**

It parses multipart HTML form content, which supports file uploads. Here also, both **`request.data` is populated with a `QueryDict`**. These have 
`.media_type` as `multipart/form-data`.

- **FileUploadParser**

It parses raw file upload content. The **`request.data` property is a dictionary** with a single key `file` containing the uploaded file.

**How does DRF [determines](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#how-the-parser-is-determined) the parser?**

When DRF accesses the `request.data`, it examines the `Content-Type` header on the incoming request and then determines which parser to use to parse the request content.

You will need to set the `Content-Type` header when sending the data otherwise it will use either a multipart or a form parser to parse the request content and give you a `QueryDict` in `request.data` instead of a dictionary.

As per DRF docs,

> If you don't set the content type, most clients will default to using
>   `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, which may not be what you wanted.

So when sending json encoded data, also set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and then it will work as expected.

**Why request.data is sometimes `QueryDict` and sometimes `dict`?**

This is done because **different encodings have different datastructures and properties.**

For example, form data is an encoding that supports multiple keys of the same value, whereas json does not support that.

Also in case of JSON data, `request.DATA` might not be a `dict` at all, it could be a list or any of the other json primitives.

Check out this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/_9cg6trvbAk) about the same.

**What you need to do?**

You can add `format='json'` in the tests when `POSTing` the data which will set the content-type as well as serialize the data correctly.

```
client.post('url', format='json', data=dict(field_a=3))
```

You can also send JSON-encoded content with `content-type` argument.

```
client.post('url', json.dumps(dict(field_a=3)), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, which nails my problem. For further reference, you could add that adding `format='json'` in the tests sets the content-type as well as serializes the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The django-rest test client doesn't automatically serialize data as json, but uses multipart/form, which results in a QueryDict.

There is, however, a format option, described [in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#setting-the-default-format). The following test code works fine:

```
client.post('url', format='json', data=dict(field_a=3))
```

I'm still puzzled on the different serializer behavior between a normal dict and a QueryDict, though...

Thanks Rajesh for pointing me in the right direction!