# Not required many field returns empty array, even if field is not set

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've a model serializer with another many model serializer field like:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField()
    status = serializers.CharField()
    participants = ParticipantSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=False)

class ParticipantSerializer(serializers.CharField):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk',)
```

Now I want to just update the status like:

```
self.client.patch('/api/my-model/{0}/'.format(pk), data={'status': 'blub'})
```

If I inspect the request, only status is set:

```
print self.request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'status': ['blub']}>
```

But the `validated_data` includes the `participants` as well with an empty array:

```
print serializer.validated_data
OrderedDict([(u'participants', []), (u'status', 'blub')])
```

Why does the serializer adds this empty array, even if the field is not required and `allow_null` is `true`?

Comment: It looks like a bug (?) in django-rest-framework, which handles encodings differently. If we use JSON instead of formencoded, it works. Similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759133/serializing-optionally-nested-structures-difference-between-querydict-and-norma